# ASP.NET MVC - POST Action Method with Additional Parameters from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders, actionmethod

With ASP.net MVC is it possible to POST a form to a controller action which includes parameters not in the form, but from the URL?

For example

The Action method in GroupController:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(int idOne, int idTwo, Model model)
    { ... }
```

The route:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{idOne}/{idTwo}"
```

Posted URL:

```
/Employee/Show/1/42
```

In this example, the form is being posted to a different controller, the model has the correct value, however the other parameters have default values 0.

The behavior I was expecting is that the ModelBinder would see that I have two parameters that match the given route, and assign the current values of 1 and 42 to the parameters in the same same way a GET operation works.

Is this behavior not supported, or am I missing something?

**EDIT**:
To be clear, the form on the `Show` view for the controller `Employee` contains a form which is posting to a different controller. We can call it `Group`.

The form action URL looks like this

```
/Groups/Create/0/0
```

The form is declared as follows

```
Html.BeginForm("Create", "Groups")
```

After trying many different overloads for `Html.BeginForm` I have found that the parameters are only mapped when the form action URL matches the current URL in the browser address bar.

So if i navigate to the URL `/Groups/Create/1/42` I will have a new form. If I then submit the form, the URL route values are passed to the POST action.

Comment: I would try defining the route to include the model and setting it as a default of null and see what happens. `{controller}/{action}/{idOne}/{idTwo}/{Model}`

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the `action` of the rendered `<form>` element pointing to URL containing route values. This should be possible with one of the overloads of the `HtmlHelper.BeginForm()` extension method:

```
Html.BeginForm("action","controller", new { idOne=1, idTwo=2 }, FormMethod.Post);
```

Let me know if I got your question all wrong :)

Comment: Sort of. As i stated in the question, the for action already contains a URL with the correct route values (1 and 42 from the example). The problem is when i step into the executing action, the two parameters have value 0. I tried your suggestion, but the values were still 0.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you can only post form data from inputs inside the form.  Have you considered rendering the view in such a way to create form input values off of the URL (perhaps with an HTML helper?).

**UPDATE:** If you don't want to use the form at all, use `ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["idOne"]` as opposed to passing it in through the method signature.

Comment: Within the form I made a query to the route values, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["idOne"], however on the final rendered page has a value of 0, not the value from the route. Is there another approach to get the current URL route values from within a View/Partial?

Comment: If you use an Html helper extension, you should be able to see it off of the helper instance itself.  The syntax would look like `helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["idOne"]`.  Alternately, you could store those ID values in a view model and pass it to the view that way.

Comment: +1 Same thoughts. Why not include the it in values as hidden fields within the Html.BeginForm("Create", "Groups")? Also, should you be 'Posting' to Create a new form?

Comment: What is the alternative to posting to create a new entity? I was trying to avoid placing hidden fields because it adds extra work for passing them between views/controllers. Especially since this functionality does work in other cases. At this point, it seems that is the only way to get past this issue

Comment: Karl - I played around with it a bit, and it looks like you can snag the values you're interested in through the `ControllerContext` object (see my update).  Let me know if that works out!

Comment: @Karl did you end up getting to the bottom of this one?

Comment: @Brandon What i ended up doing was including the id I wanted in the model itself, and passing it as a parameter to the form action. It isnt the cleanest way, but It is working for now. I tried your updated answer, however that did not return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the configuration RouteConfig has solved this problem.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
             ...
             routes.MapRoute(
             "MyRoute",
             "{controller}/{action}/{idOne}/{idTwo}",
             new
             {
                 controller = "Employee", // as an example
                 action = "Show",
                 idOne = UrlParameter.Optional,
                 idTwo= UrlParameter.Optional
             }, new { idOne = @"\d{1,5}" });

        }
    }
```

...And...
 [Html.BeginRouteForm()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginrouteform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("MyRoute", new { idOne = 1, idTwo= 2 }, FormMethod.Post))
```

> Writes an opening  tag to the response. When the user submits
>   the form, the request will be processed by the route target. 
>   This member is overloaded. For complete information about this member,
>   including syntax, usage, and examples, click a name in the overload
>   list.

And all works

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue too, and because I had a different route, it was mapping to the default route, without taking into account the extra route params that I was passing in.

So to get it working quickly, I wrote the form using form tags instead, and used @Url.Action to create the required action.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to your Create view, your route values used to get there need to be re-posted to the post action.

So, one option is having a pair of hiddens, to hold the ids that came from the route. This way, once you post the formas, its values are posted along with the other inputs.